# Field customizer: Modify values before saving?

Tags: aspx, fieldcustomizers

Is it possible to modify values before saving them to the list with SPFX field customizers? This would be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No not at the moment. Currently Field Customizers are only to display data in list view (non edit mode).

But see user voice entry [Field Customizer Evolution: Forms, Quick Edit Mode](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/20474935-field-customizer-evolution-forms-quick-edit-mode)
(and maybe upvote it)